# Is it possible to mimic excel rows in a different sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So in 'Sheet 1' I have 2000 rows of information which I add a new column to every day, I want to have only a subset of the rows of 'Sheet 1' in 'Sheet 2' which update themselves as I put new columns into 'Sheet 1'. Is this possible to do using inbuilt excel functions?

Comment: Please explain how you define the subset or are you solely interested on a solution for the columns ?

Comment: The subset is arbitrarily chosen based on which rows I want to focus on over some time period. So I might want to keep an eye on rows (10, 241, 515,...) for the near future and it would be very convenient to have them singled out in their own sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a set of particular rows and you know their row numbers, put their row   numbers (1,5,8,11,12 ...) in a separate 1 column range and name this range e.g. "RowNumbers"

Then use following normal non-array formula which you can drag downwards and rightwards.

```
= IF(INDEX(RowNumbers,ROW(A1)+1)>0, INDEX(NamedRange,INDEX(RowNumbers,ROW(A1)+1),COLUMN(B1)+1),"")
```

You will probably need to adjust the `+1` parts, depending on whether your values start at row 1 or 2 etc.

Basically the Excel `INDEX` formula does what you need - copies the value from another sheet or range by given row and column numbers.

---

Otherwise you can use following **array formula** (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to select filtered values from columns based on multiple criteria:

```
 = IFERROR(INDEX(NamedRange,
   SMALL(IF((INDEX(NamedRange,,1,1)=1)*(INDEX(NamedRange,,2,1)="A"),
   ROW(NamedRange)-MIN(ROW(NamedRange))+1,""),
   ROWS(C1:$C$1)),3,1),"")
```

[image: FormulaDesc]

Here is an example data sheet (Sheet1)

[image: Sheet1]

Here is the filtered data output sheet. You should enter the array formula in the first row and drag downwards to fill expected output range. In this example I select only rowns that have values `1` and `A` ind `filter1` and `filter2` columns.

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: This seems very close to what I'm looking for, is there an notation for multiple "passing criteria"? In this case I believe I can just add an extra column numbered 1 to 2000 and use the row numbers as my selection filtering criteria, is there a shortcut to just enter in multiple criteria or should I just copy and paste the *INDEX(...) two dozen times?

Comment: @shians What about creating a range perhaps on a separate sheet, where there would be your values 10,241,515 and then select rows that have rownumber within values in this range?

Comment: @shians Added another variant for simple filter based on the list of row numbers - just drag it as far downards or rightwards as you need.